# Is common to cypress take so much time to visit some page in nuxt project?

Tags: testing, nuxt.js, cypress

## Overview

In my project, Cypress is taking over 15s to visit a Nuxt page and then run the test

The test is running quickly, but it takes a long time to load the page.

What can I do to reduce the visit time?

## What I'm trying to do?

I want to run my e2e tests in local mode with MirageJS and in CircleCI too to validate my PRs

## Details

Cypress version: 7.4.0

Comment: Provide us more context on the configuration of your project. Asking: "my car is slow, why?" without any context is pretty hard to tell.

Comment: nuxt-webpack in dev mode 20s, nuxt-webpack in start mode (static) < 1s, nuxt-vite in dev mode <1s.

Comment: @eric true but not everything is compatible with Vite, on production it's still webpack and it will not make his app loading faster if the bottleneck is beyong the `yarn start`. And local is just out of the question at all here.

Comment: Very little is compatible with vite at the moment, but it demos the problem is with webpack HMR. Webpack + Production is ok (if target is 'static'). The rest of your message does not make sense to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Vite is for local environment only. Here, OP do have an issue with Cypress, hence E2E testing his app's performance on a production environment. So, there is nothing related to HMR or any possible Vite solution. On top of that, the issue may not come from the (build) tools but rather from his app logic, aka lot of calls, a lot of JS to parse, huge CSS framework, some blocking errors and so on. Without more context, recommending a solution is hard. Recommending a local-only solution is out of the scope tho. `target: server` is fine too since only the initial render will be done by the server.

Comment: Why do you assume he is testing the production build? It's quite possible he is developing and testing at the same time, and therefore wants dev mode with HMR.

Comment: One cannot simply test in dev env and complain about performance. And who test in local with Cypress anyway? It defeats a good amount of use-cases. On top of the fact that having a working local env is not what matters for a business. If he is testing locally, he should have no issue `yarn start` his project. Hence, the bottleneck will come beyond the start of the project (as I told previously). And I guess, it's a waste of time arguing over stuff until OP gives us more feedback.

Comment: Looks like you were right on this one. My bad I guess.

Comment: @eric99 thanks for your involvement, i tried running npm start here and it was much faster but i have a problem with my particular project. I'm using MirageJS to simulate my API requests and I don't think it's possible to build nuxt and use Mirage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally not. However there is an issue in cypress, since v7.2:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/16671

You can try to downgrade your cypress to 7.1 to evaluate if your performance-issue is related to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I very much agree with the comment that say you need to share more context with us.

However, to give you some pointers where to start:

- understand the application, what get loaded when you visit a new page, look at network requests
- does this happen only in Cypress or even when you visit a page?
- be aware of what you're testing and block everything else; Cypress has [`blockHosts` configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Browser) that can block certain requests, which in turn can significantly speed up execution; an example comes to mind: you don't need to see some ads or pictures when testing with Cypress, then you can block these requests and make your execution faster
- you can increase [timeouts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts), which won't help you speed your test suites, but at least they might not fail next time

Answer (score 0):

My teams project is NUXT based and I had trouble with render time on all versions from 5.2 to 6.8 too. Since then I made the following configuration in `cypress.json` file for increasing the default wait time:

```
{
  "requestTimeout": 60000,
  "responseTimeout": 60000
}
```

Comment: I just do this, but, as you say, isn't a solution :(